# Create new attribute with jolt transform

Tags: jolt

I try to transform

```
{
  "name": "bla",
  "latitude": 1,
  "longitude": 2
}
```

into

```
{
  "name": "bla",
  "location": {
     "latitude": 1,
     "longitude": 2
  }
}
```

with following shift operation

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "name": "name",
      "location": {
        "latitude": "&1.latitude",
        "longitude": "&1.longitude"
      },
    }
  }
]
```

However it is just creating the name field. Any ideas how I can create the location attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "name": "name",
      "latitude": "location.latitude",
      "longitude": "location.longitude"
    }
  }
]
```

Found the solution by reading the Jolt Transform DSL doc: https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java